# Spinner not showing options in kotlin fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, spinner, android-databinding

I'm trying to add options to spinner while using databinding in fragment but it's not working, I can't understand why

```
class AddTransaction: Fragment() {
private var _binding: TransactionAddFragmentBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

lateinit var spinner: Spinner

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = TransactionAddFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}

fun spinner() {
    spinner = binding.spinnerCategory
    spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        requireContext(), R.array.categories, R.layout.transaction_add_fragment)
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you call or bind the `spinner()` function?

Comment: spinner = binding.spinnerCategory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have posted, you are most likely never calling your `spinner()` function, which means you never set the adapter so it remains empty.

You were also passing `R.layout.transaction_add_fragment` to the spinner adapter, which is probably not what you wanted. The layout resource you pass in there should be for the spinner row.

Instead of putting it in a separate function, just add it to `onViewCreated`, like this:

```kotlin
class AddTransaction: Fragment() {
    private var _binding: TransactionAddFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = TransactionAddFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        
        // set the adapter here, and there is no need to make a separate "spinner"
        // class member since "binding" is already a class member that contains
        // the spinner
        binding.spinnerCategory.adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            requireContext(), R.array.categories, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the app crashed

Comment: Ah, you were also passing the wrong layout to the adapter. I updated that line to use the standard `simple_spinner_item` layout. Try it again - and if it crashes again look in the Logcat and see what the error message is.

Comment: Shouldn't the layout be where the spinner is?

Comment: No, it's the layout it uses for the individual rows of the spinner. It has to be just a single TextView or it will throw an error. Try the updated answer and see.